# Delete empty value from (sorted) dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got an arduino sending me serial data which is transposed into a dictionary.

However, not all entries have a value due data being sent at random.

Before sending the dictionary data to a CSV file I want to prune the empty values or values that are 0 from the dict.

Incoming data would look like this: (values only)

['','7','','49,'','173','158']

I want that to become

['7','49','173','158].

The script I currently use:

```
import serial
import time

def delete_Blanks(arrayName):
    tempArray = array.copy()
    for key, value in sorted(tempArray.items()):
        if value == "":
            del tempArray[key]
        else:
            print "Value is not nil"

    return tempArray

array = {}

ser = serial.Serial('COM2', 9600, timeout=1)
key = 0

while 1:
    length = len(array)
    if len(array) in range(0,5):
        array.update({key:ser.read(1000)})
        key = key + 1
        print "key is ", key
        print array.values()
        length = len(array)

    else:
        newArray = delete_Blanks(array)
        print newArray.items()
        break
```

Comment: You say that it would look like `['','7','','49,'','173','158']`. That's a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import compress

l = ['','7','','49','','173','158']
ret = compress(l, map(lambda x: bool(x), l))
print(list(ret))
```

**will output:**
['7', '49', '173', '158']

if you have long arrays of data - it's better to work with iterators to avoid memory leaks. If you work with short lists - list comprehension is just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension. This will remove all false values from a dictionary `d`:

```
d={key,d[key] for key in d if d[key]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a plain list you can do something like this

```
Mylist = filter(None, Mylist)
```

Before creating the dictionary you can filter the two list, the list containing the keys and the list containing the values. Assuming both list are the same length you can then

```
mydict = dict(zip(l1, l2))
```

to create your new list

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> li = ['','7','','49','','173','158']
>>> [e for e in li if e]
['7', '49', '173', '158']
```